# between two dates as where condition along with GETALL() method in Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have the following model. I am trying to list all the vehicles having the MOT date between two dates

```
public class Vehicles
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Make { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RegNo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string VehicleName {get;set;}
    public DateTime? MOTDate { get; set; }
```

}

My Repository class is given below

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProp);
            }
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

How can I give where condition with GetAll() method
datetime  datefrom

datetime dateto

var VehileList = VehicleRepo.GetAll()  Here I want to give where condition for MOTDate column of the model using the variable datefrom and dateto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below

`var result = GetAll(f => f.MOTDate > StarDate && f.MOTDate < EndDate);`